# js mapping function getting ignored

Tags: javascript, jsx

I have this following code in react. it gets called when i move an element. this is an example log when i move an element:

```
position2 {x: 275, y: 155}
checking collision
check collision finished
```

it doesnt execute the mapping function. no errors, no warning no crash, everything else runs fine, except this function ignoring the mapping part.

log before the mapping part "checking collision" is present, log after "check collision finished" is also there.

what could be the issue?

```js
function moveItem(position, container) {
  fixBounds(position, container);
  console.log("position2", position);
  if (!checkCollision(position, container)) {
    Object.assign(container, {
      position
    });
  }
}

function checkCollision(position, container) {
  console.log("checking collision");
  let col = false;
  containers.map((c) => {
    console.log("pos", c.position, position);
    if (c.key !== container.key) {
      const sizeA = getSize(c);
      const sizeB = getSize(container);
      const rect1 = {
        l: c.position.x,
        r: c.position.x + sizeA.w,
        t: c.position.y,
        b: c.position.y + sizeA.h,
      };
      const rect2 = {
        l: position.x,
        r: position.x + sizeB.w,
        t: position.y,
        b: position.y + sizeB.h,
      };
      if (checkOverlap(rect1, rect2)) {
        col = true;
      }
    }
  });
  console.log("check collision finished");
  return col;
}

function checkOverlap(rect1, rect2) {
  console.log("1", rect1);
  console.log("2", rect2);
  if (rect1.l >= rect2.r || rect2.l >= rect1.r) {
    console.log("no overlap");
    return false;
  } else if (rect1.t >= rect2.b || rect2.t >= rect1.b) {
    console.log("no overlap");
    return false;
  }
  console.log("overlap");
  return true;
}

function getSize(container) {
  const element = document.getElementById(container.key);
  const w = element.offsetWidth;
  const h = element.offsetHeight;
  return {
    w: w,
    h: h
  };
}
```

Comment: What is `containers`? If it's an empty array this is what you'd expect to see.

Comment: Also, you should be using `forEach` here instead of `map` since you're ignoring the returned array.

Comment: You could also use `.some()` so that it stops as soon as it detects a collision.

Comment: containers are array of container, they are never empty. i was using `every` and changed to map to see if it was any different.

Comment: @Barmar I didnt know, now i do thanks.